# I am trying to access the other parts of the 2D array whilst looping but not sure how it's exactly done

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, while-loop

This is a 2D list containing some values. I want to multiply each of the values in the list by 1.1 and if a value is equal or over than 255 then it would prompt with "burnt out". My program currently is just able to access the first list in the list and multiply it's values. I want it to do it for the others as well. Thank you.

```py
list_ = [[240,10,10,10,10,10,10,240],
         [80,80,240,80,80,240,80,80],
         [80,80,240,80,80,240,80,80],
         [80,80,150,150,150,150,80,80],
         [80,80,240,240,240,240,80,80],
         [80,80,150,150,150,150,80,80],
         [240,240,150,150,150,150,240,240],
         [240,240,150,150,150,150,240,240]]
i = 0
r =0
while i < 8:
    while r < 8:
        list_[i][r] = list_[i][r]*1.1
        if list_[i][r] > 255:
            list_[i][r] = "burnt out"
        print (list_[i][r])
        r += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: that should work. What happens?

Comment: Why are using `while` loop?

Comment: You didn't "reset" the value of `r` after the inner loop!

Comment: All that aside, this is painful to look at and work with. have you explored numpy?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple `for` loop in this case:

```
for v1 in list_:
    for i2, v2 in enumerate(v1):
        v1[i2] = v2 * 1.1
        if v1[i2] > 255:
            v1[i2] = 'BURN OUT'
```

Btw don't use reserved words (`list`) for variable names.

#### Output:

```py
[['BURN OUT', 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 'BURN OUT'],
 [88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0],
 [88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0],
 [88.0, 88.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 88.0, 88.0],
 [88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0],
 [88.0, 88.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 88.0, 88.0],
 ['BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT'],
 ['BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reset the value of r to 0 after the completion of inner loop. Otherwise, the inner loop will always test the condition with r set to 8 and hence never execute again after first time.

Updated code :

```
list = [[240,10,10,10,10,10,10,240],[80,80,240,80,80,240,80,80],[80,80,240,80,80,240,80,80],[80,80,150,150,150,150,80,80],[80,80,240,240,240,240,80,80],[80,80,150,150,150,150,80,80],[240,240,150,150,150,150,240,240],[240,240,150,150,150,150,240,240]]
i = 0
r =0
while i < 8:
    while r < 8:
        list[i][r] = list[i][r]*1.1
        if list[i][r] > 255:
            list[i][r] = "burnt out"
        print (list[i][r])
        r += 1
    i += 1
    r = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset r = 0 for every loop of i

```
list = [[240,10,10,10,10,10,10,240], 
        [80,80,240,80,80,240,80,80],
        [80,80,240,80,80,240,80,80],
        [80,80,150,150,150,150,80,80],
        [80,80,240,240,240,240,80,80],
        [80,80,150,150,150,150,80,80],
        [240,240,150,150,150,150,240,240],
        [240,240,150,150,150,150,240,240]]
i = 0
while i < 8:
    r = 0  # put inside the loop
    while r < 8:
        list[i][r] = list[i][r]*1.1
        if list[i][r] > 255:
            list[i][r] = "burnt out"
        print (list[i][r])
        r += 1
    i += 1
```

In your code, r = 8 for i > 0

Answer (score 0):

Most pythonic way to do this using list comprehension and map function

```py
nlist = [[240, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 240],
 [80, 80, 240, 80, 80, 240, 80, 80],
 [80, 80, 240, 80, 80, 240, 80, 80],
 [80, 80, 150, 150, 150, 150, 80, 80],
 [80, 80, 240, 240, 240, 240, 80, 80],
 [80, 80, 150, 150, 150, 150, 80, 80],
 [240, 240, 150, 150, 150, 150, 240, 240],
 [240, 240, 150, 150, 150, 150, 240, 240]]

nlist[:] = [list(map(lambda x: x*1.1 if x*1.1<=255 else 'BURN OUT',sub_list)) for sub_list in nlist]
```

Output:

```
[['BURN OUT', 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 'BURN OUT'],
 [88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0],
 [88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0],
 [88.0, 88.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 88.0, 88.0],
 [88.0, 88.0, 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 88.0, 88.0],
 [88.0, 88.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 88.0, 88.0],
 ['BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT'],
 ['BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT', 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 165.0, 'BURN OUT', 'BURN OUT']]
```